# What is the smallest and largest relation from $S \to T$?

Tags: combinatorics

$S$ will stand for a finite set of size $s$ and $T$ will stand for a finite set of size $t$.
(a) What is the size of the largest relation from $S$ to $T$?
(b) What is the size of the smallest relation from $S$ to $T$?
(c) The relation of a function $f$ : $S$ $\to$ $T$ is the set of all ordered
pairs $(x, f(x))$ with $x \in S$. What is the size of the relation of a
function from $S$ to $T$? That is, how many ordered pairs are in
the relation of a function from $S$ to $T$?

I don't know if these questions are just really simple or I'm just not seeing something?
For (a) and (b) I think the size of both the largest and smallest relations from $S$ to $T$ is $s$ because in order for this to be a valid function every element from the domain $(S)$ needs to be used and they also can't be used more than once. Is this correct?

For (c) I think there are $s$ ordered pairs in the relation, but this seems like it's basically asking the same idea as in parts (a) and (b)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasoning for (a) and (b) makes it out like the relations need to be functions, but that isn't indicated at all in the question as stated.  If you're thinking of a relation as a subset of $S\times T$, then the smallest subset is $\emptyset$ and the largest is $S\times T$, giving you the smallest and largest relations, respectively.

Your answer for (c) looks good; there's exactly one ordered pair for each element of $S$, so there are $s$ ordered pairs.

Comment: After reading it again I realize it's not asking for a function. I understand why the smallest would be the empty set, but would the size of the largest relation be max($s, t$)?

Comment: Well, the largest thing in $S\times T$ is $S\times T$ itself.  How many elements are in $S\times T$?

Comment: I keep thinking about functions, $S \times T$ is like if $s=5$ and $t=6$ the largest relation would be $5 \times 6 = 30$ because each element in $S$ can be mapped to more than one element in $T$, unlike a function.

Comment: @idknuttin Yep, though I would warn you against thinking about relations as partial functions which allow mapping to more than one thing, as this sometimes gets in the way of intuition.  For example, $\leq$ is a relation on $\mathbb{R}$ which we don't think of as a function, but instead of a way of ordering things.